# preg_match_all not matching contents on a different line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I was writing a regex match pattern, when I suddenly found out that preg_match_all isn't matching contents on a different line. What's up with that, and how do I fix it?

**test1.php**

```
$content = file_get_contents("test2.php");
preg_match_all("~startMatch(.+?)endMatch~", $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**test2.php**

```
startMatch text 
endMatch
```

**Results:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

**Expected Results:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => startMatch text endMatch ) [1] => Array ( [0] => text ) )
```

However, we get the expected result, if `startMatch text endMatch` is on the same line. What's up with that? Don't periods in regex match all characters? How do I fix it?

Comment: Although I do not suggest that approach, I decided that the question is still a duplicate. You should learn to use unrolling-the-loop technique to forget about `/s` and enjoy high regex performance. Something like `startMatch([^e]*(e(?!ndMatch)[^e]*)*)endMatch`

Comment: @Mariano If I didn't stumble across this little fun fact today, I would forever think that somehow I'm always writing my patterns incorrectly.

Comment: @stribizhev The what technique? How do I use that?

Comment: @stribizhev That pattern makes my head hurt trying to read it. Would using the 's' flag really slow down the performance to a noticeable degree? If not, I'd rather prefer to use the simpler flag.

Comment: You should choose between readability and performance. Also, if you work with short strings, `.*?` or `.+?` is preferable.

Comment: @frosty This article explains the concept http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap